# Am I disturbing other programs with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm using OpenMP for a loop like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int out = 1; out <= matrix.rows; out++)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm doing a lot of computations on a machine with 64 CPUs. This works quite qell but my question is:
Am I disturbing other users on this machine? Usually they only run single thread programms. Will they still run on 100%? Obviously I will disturb other multithreads programms, but will I disturb single thread programs?
If yes, can I prevend this? I think a can set the maximum number of CPUs with  `omp_set_num_threads`. I can set this to 60, but I don't think this is the best solution.
The ideal solution would disturb no other single thread programs but take as much CPUs as possible.

Comment: You do not need to call `omp_set_num_threads()` in order to control the amount of threads. Simply set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable to the desired max number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

Every multitasking OS has something called a process scheduler. This is an OS component that decides where and when to run each process. Schedulers are usually quite stubborn in the decisions they make but those could often be influenced by various user-supplied policies and hints. The default configuration for almost any scheduler is to try and spread the load over all available CPUs, which often results in processes migrating from one CPU to another. Fortunately, any modern OS except "the most advanced desktop OS" (a.k.a. OS X) supports something called processor affinity. Every process has a set of processors on which it is allowed to execute - the so-called CPU affinity set of that process. By configuring disjoint affinity sets to various processes, those could be made to execute concurrently without stealing CPU time from each other. Explicit CPU affinity is supported on Linux, FreeBSD (with the ULE scheduler), Windows NT (this also includes all desktop versions since Windows XP), and possibly other OSes (but not OS X). Every OS then provides a set of kernel calls to manipulate the affinity and also an instrument to do that without writing a special program. On Linux this is done using the `sched_setaffinity(2)` system call and the `taskset` command line instrument. Affinity could also be controlled by creating a `cpuset` instance. On Windows one uses the `SetProcessAffinityMask()` and/or `SetThreadAffinityMask()` and affinities can be set in Task Manager from the context menu for a given process. Also one could specify the desired affinity mask as a parameter to the `START` shell command when starting new processes.

What this all has to do with OpenMP is that most OpenMP runtimes for the listed OSes support under one form or another ways to specify the desired CPU affinity for each OpenMP thread. The simplest control is the `OMP_PROC_BIND` environment variable. This is a simple switch - when set to `TRUE`, it instructs the OpenMP runtime to "bind" each thread, i.e. to give it an affinity set that includes a single CPU only. The actual placement of threads to CPUs is implementation dependent and each implementation provides its own way to control it. For example, the GNU OpenMP runtime (`libgomp`) reads the [`GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html#GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY) environment variable, while the Intel OpenMP runtime (open-source since not long ago) reads the [`KMP_AFFINITY`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/optaps/common/optaps_openmp_thread_affinity.htm) environment variable.

The rationale here is that you could limit your program's affinity in such a way as to only use a subset of all the available CPUs. The remaining processes would then get predominantly get scheduled to the rest of the CPUs, though this is only guaranteed if you manually set their affinity (which is only doable if you have root/Administrator access since otherwise you can modify the affinity only of processes that you own).

It is worth mentioning that it often (but not always) makes no sense to run with more threads than the number of CPUs in the affinity set. For example, if you limit your program to run on 60 CPUs, then using 64 threads would result in some CPUs being oversubscribed and in timesharing between the threads. This will make some threads run slower than the others. The default scheduling for most OpenMP runtimes is `schedule(static)` and therefore the total execution time of the parallel region is determined by the execution time of the slowest thread. If one thread timeshares with another one, then both threads will execute slower than those threads that do not timeshare and the whole parallel region would get delayed. Not only this reduces the parallel performance but it also results in wasted cycles since the faster threads would simply wait doing nothing (possibly busy looping at the implicit barrier at the end of the parallel region). The solution is to use dynamic scheduling, i.e.:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,chunk_size)
for (int out = 1; out <= matrix.rows; out++)
{
    ...
}
```

where `chunk_size` is the size of the iteration chunk that each thread gets. The whole iteration space is divided in chunks of `chunk_size` iterations and are given to the worker threads on a first-come-first-served basis. The chunk size is an important parameter. If it is too low (the default is 1), then there could be a huge overhead from the OpenMP runtime managing the dynamic scheduling. If it is too high, then there might not be enough work available for each thread. It makes no sense to have chunk size bigger than `maxtrix.rows / #threads`.

Dynamic scheduling allows your program to adapt to the available CPU resources, even if they are not uniform, e.g. if there are other processes running and timesharing with the current one. But it comes with a catch: big system like your 64-core one usually are ccNUMA (cache-coherent non-uniform memory access) systems, which means that each CPU has its own memory block and access to the memory block(s) of other CPU(s) is costly (e.g. takes more time and/or provides less bandwidth). Dynamic scheduling tends to destroy data locality since one could not be sure that a block of memory, which resides on one NUMA, won't get utilised by a thread running on another NUMA node. This is especially important when data sets are large and do not fit in the CPU caches. Therefore YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Put your process on low priority within the operating system. Use a many resources as you like. If someone else needs those resources the OS will make sure to provide them, because they are on a higher (i.e. normal) priority. If there are no other users you will get all resources.

Comment: Ok, that sound good. But if another user with 64 threads will come, my process will have to wait. Maybe its good practise to tell all users using multiple threads to put them on low priority. And only single thread processes will use normal priority?